# Delay UITableView from hiding UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiviewanimation

My problem is that I have a UIContainerView that has a subView of UITableView. 
When a user presses a button this UIContainerView toggles opened/closed by animating its frame size.
The issue I have is that, because the frame size is set immediately and the animation happens over time, the TableView cells get "dequeued" and disappear, before the animation is complete. I'm guessing because the tableView thinks it is no longer being displayed.

Is there anyway to delay this, until the animation is complete. Perhaps in the completion section of +(void)animateWithDuration:...

Comment: I guess the table view is also resizing during the animation? Try setting the table view to not resize as the container resizes and ensure that the container view does not allow drawing outside the bounds (-clipsToBounds).

Comment: That could be it, I think it may resize using struts and springs.

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty solution would be to add in an opaque UIView at the bottom of the frame, and animate it upward to give the collapsing effect. In the completion block of the animateWithDuration method, you could then change the frame of the container view.

It's hard to give a really good answer without knowing the visual effect you are trying to achieve. A more proper way would be to delete table view cells to give an animation effect, but it might not look exactly right...

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval) animations:^{
        //Animation code
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        //after animation completion
    }]
```

I think you can user this. what ever you what to do after animation, you can write it in completion block.